# passing interface as function parameter (PHP)?

Tags: php, polymorphism

I am watching one of Jeffs Laracast Tutorials about coding rules.

```
function signUp($subscription) 
{
    if ($subscription == 'monthly')
    {
        $this->createMonthlySubscription();
    }
    elseif ($subscription == 'forever')
    {
        $this->createForeverSubscription();
    }
 }
```

He wants to use polymorphism and interfaces here. He changes the above code to:

```
function signUp(Subscription $subscription)
{
    $subscription->create();
}
```

I don't understand what he is doing here. Is he passing the interface "Subscription" as a function parameter..? I never saw this in all previous tutorials about interfaces.

Comment: Are you sure `$subscription` is an interface and not a class?

Comment: `$subscription` should be an object of class that implements `Subscription` interface. So, you don't need to specify a certain class as function's parameter

Comment: This is a so called type hint. Look here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
function signUp(Subscription $subscription)
{
    $subscription->create();
}
```

This methods expects a single paramater called `$subscription`. This paramater has to be a concrete object (or `null`) that *implements* the `Subscription` interface.

This is done via a so called "type hint" (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) before the parameter.

`Subscription` does not need to be an interface here - it could also be a class, and the given parameter must either be an instance of `Subscription` or any derived type.

Answer (score 3):

here is the detail explanation according to your given case I hope so after that you will understand this concept properly

```
Interface Subscription{
    public function create();
}

class MonthlySubscription implements Subscription{

    public function create(){
        print_r("this is monthly subscription create method");
    }

}

class ForeverSubscription implements Subscription{

public function create(){
        print_r("this is yearly subscription create method");
    }   

}


class user {

public function signUp(Subscription $subscription){

    $subscription->create();

}

public function getSubcriptionType($type){

if($type=='forever'){

    return new ForeverSubscription;

}

    return new MonthlySubscription;

}


}

$user=new User();

$subscription=$user->getSubcriptionType('forever');

$user->signUP($subscription);
```

```
public function signUp(Subscription $subscription){
    $subscription->create();
}
```

In this method you are trying to do ***method injection*** 
method injection ***means*** passing a dependency(instance/refference/object etc) into a method

> in Singup(Subscription $subscription) mentod

*Subscription* is a '**type hint**'

which ensure that object that will be pass to signUp() function must be an instance of that class who  implemented '**Subscription** ' interface